# how to observe changes in an array in vb .net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

i have an array A, i just want to monitor the changes in that array, return the changed position of that array.

```
 myOldTextBox = myTextBox
            myTextBox = New TextBox() {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5}
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 0 To myTextBox.Length - 1
                If myTextBox(i).Text <> myOldTextBox(i).Text Then
                    Dim fs As Integer
                    fs = farray.Length
                    farray(fs) = i
                End If

            Next i
```

i am newbie in vb .net. Thank you.

Comment: How do you want it to be monitored? by placing the number of the changed array in a listbox?

Comment: I can't see the rest of the code, do you have the reference of the TextBox? If you don't, then you'll always be comparing the same .Text. Also, you'll have an overflow error if you do farray(farray.Length) = i. I would suggest you handle the TextChanged event of the textbox to figure out if the value is changing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can do that.

For a regular variable I would suggest using get/set.

For an array, I would suggest creating a method to update the values, instead of setting the values directly (you can enforce this by making the array private and only giving it access through a get and set method).

In that method you can then do anything you want.

Pseudo code:

```
private _array
Public Function GetArray(ByVal key As String) As String
    return _array(key)
End Function

Public Function SetArray(ByVal key As String, ByVal val As String) as String
    _array(key) = val

   return val;
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

add a listbox, and whenever the if condition is satisfied, add content to the listbox

```
        myTextBox = New TextBox() {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5}
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To myTextBox.Length - 1
            If myTextBox(i).Text <> myOldTextBox(i).Text Then
                Dim fs As Integer
                fs = farray.Length
                farray(fs) = i

                Listbox1.items.add(Format(now,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") & _
                " array number changed: " & i
            End If

        Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: (Didn't notice you were doing what I posted)

I would change the For loop to a Do While loop, because I have found issues when comparing substring in a For Loop, try it and see if that doesn't fix your problem...

(I've even tried Microsoft code that failed in for Loops w/ substrings)

Also, I'd HIGHLY suggest you use a MessageBox.Show(sMsg) or Debug.WriteLine(sMsg) to ENSURE that data is correct...